# iPad is getting calls from my iPhone

Tags: ipad

My iPad keeps ringing when I get a call on my iPhone.  I have disabled FaceTime and Messages, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm going to close this as duplicate. If it's not, please edit the post to explain the steps you took to disable FaceTime and disable messages. Be sure to address what you did on each device and possibly include the iOS versions for both.

Answer (score 2):

Under Settings > Facetime there's a seperate switch for "iPhone mobile calls" (on the iPad). That should be off. If you're still getting the calls try resetting your iPad, make sure you have a backup first.

Answer (score 0):

Check if handoff is on that could be why you are receiving calls on your device.

To do this,  go to settings > general > handoff and suggested apps

- the **toggle** for handoff should be at the top of that page